# Source of multicast broadcast to WAN port

Tags: router, firewall, multicast

I have noticed multicast broadcasts from 192.168.30.2 hitting my router's WAN interface. That would be sourced from an interface that's somewhere locally on my router, right, or where would it be coming from on the ISP's 10.46.xx.xx network? Thanks!

Here's the firewall log. The first item's source IP is within /24 of my WAN's gateway IP. The second item's source IP's subnet seems like a local private IP but where would it be? It seems maybe like a handshake over the Remote Replication Agent Connection port.

`Thu Jun 25 02:34:12 2020 kern.warn kernel: [ 8257.329619] DROP wan in: IN=eth0.2 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:64:d1:54:84:83:02:08:00:45:00:00:80 SRC=10.46.32.37 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=5678 DPT=5678 LEN=108`

`Thu Jun 25 02:34:12 2020 kern.warn kernel: [ 8257.440217] DROP wan in: IN=eth0.2 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:d4:ca:6d:0b:9b:05:08:00:45:00:00:8b SRC=192.168.30.2 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=139 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=5678 DPT=5678 LEN=119`

Comment: Where do you get your internet connection from? Is the WAN connection a dedicated line that goes directly from your house to the ISP, or is it a shared connection in an apartment building or university dorms or something?

Comment: Goes directly to the ISP...but then it's all going to some shared switch for several units.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems maybe like a handshake over the Remote Replication Agent Connection port.

It's a Mikrotik RouterOS [discovery](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Neighbor_discovery) packet. RouterOS collects such packets from other nearby routers in order to show a nice list of what other infrastructure devices (routers, switches) are connected to each port. It's similar in purpose to [LLDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol) and CDP.

(Although by now vendor-specific discovery protocols are deprecated in favor of LLDP, in RouterOS it's all-or-nothing – if discovery is enabled it sends out announcements using MNDP, CDP, *and* LLDP. The latter two just don't show up in your iptables logs as they are not IP-based.)

> The first item's source IP is within /24 of my WAN's gateway IP.

Not very unusual. WAN links are not necessarily point-to-point; it's very possible that it would be a regular subnet with some routers and some customers, especially with a smaller ISP.

> The second item's source IP's subnet seems like a local private IP but where would it be?

It is likely that the same Layer-2 connection has multiple IP subnets on it (for whatever reason). That is, both 10.46.32.37 and 192.168.30.2 are actual devices on your WAN link – both of them Mikrotik routers.